# Reactivate PayPal profile after status expired

Tags: paypal-sandbox

We are implementing recurring payment profile in asp.net. we are using merchant account payment process.

Please advice us to resolve below mentioned scenario:

We have to perform recurring payment process as monthly and also per 6 months. Currently we have started recurring payment for 6 month package. 
Below are parameters for recurring payment as listed:
Billing cycle :- 6
Billing Period :- Month
Billing Frequency :- 1.

So as per above parameter my recurring payment will be done on:
1st payment : 23-07-2015
2nd payment : 23-08-2015
3rd payment : 23-09-2015
4th payment : 23-10-2015
5th payment : 23-11-2015
6th payment : 23-12-2015

After 6 month payment, i want to continue my recurring payment for another 6 month package. But the issue is that, after 6 month payment, my total billing cycle is 0 and my profile status become expired. So i can't renew my package for next 6 month. And cannot reactivate my profile as its status is expired.

When i trying to update my profile after 6 month payment, i get response from PayPal is "Profile is not active".

As we have to update profile as active instead of "expired", we have tried multiple methods but no one is working properly. So please let us know by which method we can reactivate the profile. also if possible please provide parameters with method name.

Let me know if any solution for the same. it will be very needful to us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES and TOTALBILLINGCYCLES to implement your goal.

For first 6 month package, please use "trial" parameter for CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API . Like as below,

TRIALBILLINGPERIOD = Month

TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY = 1

TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES = 6

Then after 6 month payment, it can be started formal payment for 6 month package.

BILLINGPERIOD = Month

BILLINGFREQUENCY = 6

TOTALBILLINGCYCLES = 0 or not specified. (the regular payment period continues until the profile is canceled or deactivated.)

Above operation will help you solve the issue.